# How to check the status of bash shell script while executing from Python script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, scp

I have a simple Python script which will execute a shell script using `subprocess` module in Python.

Below is my Python shell script which is calling `testing.sh` shell script and it works fine.

```
import os
import json
import subprocess

jsonData = '{"pp": [0,3,5,7,9]}'
jj = json.loads(jsonData)

os.putenv( 'jj3', ' '.join( str(v) for v in jj['pp']  ) )

print "start"
proc = subprocess.Popen('testing.sh', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(stdout, stderr) = proc.communicate()
if stderr:
   print "Shell script gave some error"
   print stderr
else:
   print stdout
   print "end" # Shell script ran fine.
```

And below is my `testing.sh` shell script -

```
#!/bin/bash

dir1=some_directory
dir2=some_directory

length1=some_number
length2=some_number

if [ "$dir1" = "$dir2" ] && [ "$length1" -gt 0 ] && [ "$length2" -gt 0 ]
then
    for el in $jj3
    do
        scp david@machineB:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_"$el"_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_"$el"_5.data /data01/primary/.
    done        
fi
```

What my above shell script does is, it will copy the files from `machineB` OR `machineC` to `machineA`. If the files are not there in `machineB` then it should be there in `machineC` always. So it will try to copy the files from `machineB` to `machineA` but if the files are not there in `machineB` then it will try to copy the files from `machineC` to `machineA`.

Now my above Python script (which I am running from `machineA`) tries to execute my above shell script and see whether my script got executed successfully or not. As I am storing the `stderr` of my shell script and `stdout` as well.

**Problem Statement:-**

With the above approach there is one problem that I am seeing. As I mentioned if the files are not there in `machineB`, then it will try to copy the files from `machineC` to `machineA`. So whenever I run my Python script which calls my shell script, what happens is that, some files are not there in `machineB` so it throws some exception and then it tries copying the files from `machineC` but when the call comes back to Python script, it always go inside `if stderr:` block as there was an error while copying the files from `machineB` (which is not what I want) and `end` print statement doesn't gets printed out.

So the question is if the files are not there in `machineB`, it will try copying the files from `machineC` and if the file is there is `machineC` and got successfully copied to `machineA` without any error, then I want to call that as a `success` instead of `failure`. In current scenario what is happening, if the files are not there in `machineB` and got successfully copied from `machineC` then it still counts as a failure and `end` print statement doesn't gets printed out.

I also want to see whether my shell script has any problem while executing from Python. If yes, then I don't want to print `end` statement.

How should I overcome this problem?

**UPDATED:-**

What will happen with the below shell script? As the first `for` loop will failed because `david` is not a linux command, but my `scp` command works fine. So still I will see status code as not equal to `0`?

```
for i in $( david ); do
    echo item: $i
done

dir1=some_directory
dir2=some_directory

length1=some_number
length2=some_number

if [ "$dir1" = "$dir2" ] && [ "$length1" -gt 0 ] && [ "$length2" -gt 0 ]
then
    for el in $jj3
    do
        scp david@machineB:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_"$el"_5.data /data01/primary/. || scp david@machineC:/data/be_t1_snapshot/20131215/t1_"$el"_5.data /data01/primary/.
    done        
fi
```

Comment: Why not just use [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)?

Comment: Never worked before so need to spend some time to understand and setup in my production machines. I have worked with SCP before so was aware how to do it. And I am not sure how easy it is for my current problem definition. As I need to execute this shell script from Python.

Comment: Seriously. I would use rsync over ssh, I would not pick `scp` to keep files in sync across three machines.

Comment: I will try to read more about rsync and see how easily I can incorporate it with my current problem. But for now, I will try to look for solution with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

A process which worked correctly can still write to `stderr`, so it is wrong to check for problems using `if stderr:`

Instead you should check the processes exit code. If it is not equal to zero, there was an error, e.g:

```
[...]
if proc.returncode != 0:
    print "Shell script gave some error"
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I updated my question with another simple shell script. What will happen in that scenario? I will see status code not equal to zero if any of the command in my shell script failed or only the last command?

Comment: @SSH By default shell scripts tend to ignore errors and happily carry on. In bash, you can use `set -o errexit` so the script will exit on error (with a non-zero exit code)

Comment: But if I am using `set -o errexit` in my shell script. And if it tries to copy the file from `machineB` and if the files is not there in `machineB` so it throws an exception but that file will be there in `machineC` so it will copy the files from `machineC`. But if I am using `set -o errexit` then it will stop the shell script as soon as it tries to copy the file from `machineB` which is also not what I want?